# Pont of contact tangent_Circle

Tags: circles

The point of contact between a line $lx+my+n$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ is $(-a^2l/n,-a^2m/n)$

What is the POC between the same line and the circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever this '*point of contact*' means, if we assume that it is invariant under translation by any vector, or in other words, invariant under coordinate transformations $x\to x+g$ and $y\to y+f$, then, introducing the new coordinates of the shifted coordinate system
 $$X:=x+g,\ Y:=y+f\,,$$
for the circle we have $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=X^2+Y^2-g^2-f^2+c$, so let us set $A^2:=g^2+f^2-c\ $ (note that it should be positive in order to get a circle), and the line becomes
$$lx+my+n=lX+mY-lg-mf+n$$
So, set $N:=n-lg-mf$, and then this 'point of contact' will be
$$(X,Y)=\left(-\frac{A^2l}N,-\frac{A^2m}N\right)$$
and so, using $X=x+g$ and $Y=y+f$, we have
$$(x,y)=\left(-\frac{A^2l}N-g,-\frac{A^2m}N-f\right)\,.$$

Comment: Many thanks for your help!!